# How get the referenced entity inside a field link?

Tags: entities, 9

I'm on D9. I've a paragraph with a *Link* field.
I need to get the referenced entity programmatically.

What I've managed so far is:

```php
       $nid = NULL;
       $field_link = $paragraph->get('field_link')->first();
       $route_params = $field_link->getUrl()->getRouteParameters();
        
        if(isset($route_params['node'])) {
          $nid = $route_params['node'];
        }

       if($nid) {
               ....
       }
```

But looks quite convoluted to me - and rely on the fact that the entity linked is only of type 'node'. Isn't there some function that provide the data directly\ in a more robust way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using this code for a very similar task:

```
/** @var $link \Drupal\Core\Url */
if (!$link->isRouted()) {
  /* internal unrouted or external link */
  return;
}

$route = $link->getRouteParameters();
$entityType = key($route);
$referencedEntity = NULL;
try {
  $referencedEntity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage($entityType)
    ->load($route[$entityType]);
  $referencedEntity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')
    ->getTranslationFromContext($referencedEntity);
}
catch (Throwable $t) {
  /* Don't know if this is necessary, but I don't know what is coming out of getRouteParameters() */
  return;
}

if (!($referencedEntity instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase)) {
  /* maybe you want to allow different kind of entities here, e.g. a webform is no content entity */
  return;
}

/* success */
doStuff($referencedEntity);
```

Basically the same you are already doing, but you can use the key to get the entity type and make it more generic.

Comment: Great code example. To make it more predictable what is in getRouteParameters() I would check first getRouteName() for a pattern like `entity.ENTITY_TYPE.canonical`.